# Why does interchanging two rows flip the sign of the determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

In the book there is a property of the determinant that I have question about:

> If B is a matrix obtained by interchanging any two rows or interchanging any two columns of an n by n matrix A, then $det(B)=-det(A)$

It is left without proof. I would like to know why this is true. Any references or any help are appreciated.